# Question concerning a "scope conflict"/"turf war" in the movie "Lock Up" (1989)

Tags: plot-explanation, lock-up

I'm not a native English speaker, so sorry for my English. A few months ago I've seen the movie ["Lock Up"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_Up_%28film%29).
There was a "turf war" (how to say this in formal English: "scope clash/conflict"?) 
The warden/prison director wants to bully an immate of his prison. But more and more the "Captain" of the prison refuses to tolerate the behaviour of the director. At the end of the movie both try to arrest each other. They also quarrel, whether it is legal.

My question is: What is a "Captain" in a prison? Which of both outranks the other? Or are they independent of each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a simple answer to your question is that the Warden has full jurisdiction over every aspect of a prison.  A Captain leads the guards, but has no jurisdiction over the infirmary, mess hall, etc...  Therefore, the Warden outranks the Captain.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Is this circumstance, that a warden never has jurisdiction over the guards, a real fact in the USA? Maybe it's overemphasized in the movie so that the evil warden can be overmastered..

Comment: Anyone can question the sanity or efficiency of a superior.  In this movie, I believe the Captain had morals and the Warden did not, so the Captain was able to question the Warden's ability to run the prison.